# Highlight keyword in video search result in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results

I am trying to search for certain videos in my video result source.

I am able to get the the results correctly.

But I am not able to highlight the searched keyword in the result.

How can this be done?

Comment: Please check following post
[HitHighlighted Property](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nadeemis/archive/2012/10/16/applying-hit-highlighting-to-any-property-in-the-search-results-webpart-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

Comment: @VarunVerma that does not solve my problem, as for video search we will have content only in the title, title is already present in the hithighlighted property. Still it is not highlighted. So we need to enable this through some other methods.